# wordpress parse error

Tags: wordpress

I'm editing a wordpress template, called BlueGrey (download : http://www.skinpress.com/bluegrey-theme-2/ )

But I've a problem. when I edit index.php and run myblog, php said:

> Parse error: parse error in
>   C:\wamp\www*******\wp-content\themes\BlueGrey\index.php on line 52

line 52 ::

i pasted index.php (edited version) in pastebin:: http://pastebin.com/EMtxJN4h

note 1::: i have this problem on WAMP, and Xampp run it perfectly.

note 2::: original index.php has not any problem ::: ht tp://pastebin.com/cmqJHqeh

Thanks.

Comment: skinpress and bluegrey template no more exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using {} instead of : endwhile;
Also try enabling shorttag in wamp.
Or You can just turn error reporting off in php.ini

You can copy your php.ini file from Xamp installation to Wamp, because it is working fine in Xamp as mentioned by you.

Comment: How can `Or You can just turn error reporting off in php.ini` be a viable solution? Hiding an error instead of correcting it is just... wrong. :\

Comment: I advised turning error reporting off because of "note 1::: i have this problem on WAMP, and Xampp run it perfectly". If you are in production state then you wont want to show errors to your visitors.

Answer (score 0):

On line 47 you have:

```
<?
```

By default WAMP likes the full opening of:

```
<?php
```